# Help Critique deck post and beam location

Tags: deck, decking

please critique my deck design and post locations. One side of the deck will be attached to multiple ledger boards, another sitting on the beam with 1 feet overhang. Deck is at most 1 1/2 feet of the ground at some places. Grey area is existing concrete steps for the door on the right to them. Joists are 12 inch of center, 2 x 6 sized for a composite deck

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not a structural engineer but i have built decks so take my opinion for what it is worth.  Your post spacing looks good, But we do not know what size beams you are using and that matters in order to know if they are adequate.

I would move your first beam in towards the house 2' so it is 8' from the wall. That way each joist run is 8'

2x6 for joist is inadequate. Your long run of joists ( 10 feet ) will require  that your joists be at least 2x10 lumber.

I might use 16 foot joists so they run over both beams instead of having  the first beam be a double ledger.

There are online [deck calculators](https://www.decks.com/calculators/beamsandfootingsizes) that you plug in your dimensions and it will tell you what size joists and beams and posts specs you need.